# C# Convert yyyymmdd to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to convert the UTC Time on Server that located overseas to local time e.g. Australia. Could anyone please help me to achieve this

Thanks.

Comment: Sure! What have you tried yourself, so far? What trouble are you running into? Any relevant code?

Answer (score 10):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd").ToLocalTime()
```

The `MM` needs to be capital, because `mm` means minutes, not months.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.Parse()`.

If the input string does not have the timezone offset included (for example, `03/01/2009 05:42:00 -5:00`, `Sat, 01 Nov 2008 19:35:00 GMT` or `2008-11-01T19:35:00.0000000-07:00`), then ensure that the DateTme.Kind is "Utc", then call DateTime.ToLocal() to convert it to the local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Would you not be better using

```
DateTime.TryParse(String DateString, out DateTime result)
```

Then should anything be wrong you won't get the exception thrown - you can check the values instead (or use a IF)!